# Adobe Illustrator export the PNG as edited size?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, png, image-format

I want to export the created file as a png on Adobe Illustrator cs6. I exported the file as png but also it had been as a png file, it wasn't as I wanted size. How to set the png size as I wanted.

[image: Adobe Illustrator]

The exported picture is given below. But I want to above size for png file. So How to set png file size manually.

[image: The png file after exported]

Comment: Instead of using "**Export**" use "**Save for web**", choose PNG format file and change the size in that window. Also you should adjust the artboard on the AI file. Select the object and go to menu > Object > Artboards >Fit to selected object.

Comment: Your question isn't very clear.  Do you want it to be the same size as shown on-screen, in Illustrator?  Then just take a screenshot of it.

Comment: I want to export png as size to "artboard" width and height. But I exported the png, I was got png as I given above.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure I understand you correctly, but it seems you want to export the whole artboard, and not just the artwork itself.

This could be easily achieved by checking *Use Artboards* (in the bottom of the dialogue) when exporting:

[image]

Alternatively, you could use *File > Save for Web...* where you have even more control.

Comment: Can I want to change resolution as wanted to do?

Comment: The default resolution is 72ppi. But, if you increase it to 144 it will have double the size in pixels if you open it on a web browser. If you open it back in Illustrator it will have the same size you made it but it will show you 144ppi. You can change it in the next dialog box.